# Is it possible to replace callModule with moduleServer when the module function has extra parameters?

Tags: r, shiny

```r
module_function <- function(input, 
                            output, 
                            session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain(), 
                            env,
                            con)
```

The above is the module function API. It currently works with `callModule`:

```r
callModule(module = module_function, id = "ID", env = env, con = conn)
```

because of the `...`:

```r
callModule(module, id, ..., session = getDefaultReactiveDomain())
```

However, if one wishes to replace `callModule` with `moduleServer`, is it possible since

```r
moduleServer(id, module, session = getDefaultReactiveDomain())
```

does not have the `...`?

Note, the API of `module_function` cannot be changed since it is defined in some other package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to follow the new style like this

```r
myServer <- function(id, param1, param2, ...){ # replace paramX and ... with your params
    module <- function(input, output, session){
        ... # module code
    }
    moduleServer(id, module)
}
```

On top-level server you directly call the module function instead of using `callModule`

```r
myServer(id = "xxx", param1 = xxx, param2 = xxx)
```

A small example look like this:

```r
## module start ----
library(shiny)
myUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    div(
        h2(id),
        verbatimTextOutput(ns("text"))
    )
    
}
myServer <- function(id, value1, value2){
    module <- function(input, output, session){
        output$text <- renderPrint(cat(id, ":", value1, " ", value2))
    }
    moduleServer(id, module)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    myUI("a"),
    myUI("b")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    myServer("a", 1, 2)
    myServer("b", 3, 4)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]